# Using row number in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I use the row number of a spreadsheet in a column formula? I need to do a calculation on a column (that contains several thousand rows, so manual entry is not an option) that multiplies the row number by a certain amount. I'm using Excel 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW()` to return the current row number.